# remove /dev/mapper/fedora-root and /dev/mapper/fedora-swap

Tags: devices

I want to replace Fedora 18 with Ubuntu but I have these devices listed when partitioning. I only have a hard disk labelled sda, where does these virtual device come from? How I do remove them?

Answer (score 1):

Those "devices" are part of the LVM machinery. I don't know Ubuntu, but it should recognize the LVM layout and offer to keep it on install.